# ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'get_object_queryset'

Tags: python, django, object, many-to-many

I’m really new in python and a need your help please!
I’m trying to display a list of “anomalie” objects only showing the elements that corresponds to the “User” according to the “Aisles” assigned to him (in a many-to-many relationship)
So the model.py is as follows:

```
class Aisle(models.Model):
    aisle_code = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    aisle_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.aisle_name

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return bool(self.aisle_name or self.aisle_name)


class Account (AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)  
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    store = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aisle = models.ManyToManyField(Aisle)  
    user_identification = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                       'phone_number', 'role', 'store', 'aisle', 'user_identification']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

       def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def staff(self):
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def active(self):
        return self.is_active


class Anomalie (models.Model):
    ANOMALIE = (
        ("Etiquette absente", "Etiquette absente"),
        ("Etiquette decalee", "Etiquette decalee"),
        ("Etiquette inconnue", "Etiquette inconnue"),
    )

    ANOMALIE_STATE = (
        ("traité", "traité"),
        ("mise à jour", "mise à jour"),
        ("signalé", "signalé"),


    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=ANOMALIE, null=False)
    date_report = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)

  
    localization = models.TextField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=ANOMALIE_STATE, null=False)
  
    aisle = models.ForeignKey(Aisle, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   

    def datepublished(self):
        return self.date_report.strftime('%B %d %Y')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

When I’m trying to get the objects query set in the view.py, an error occurs, so the question is how could I get the query set objects in a many-to-many relationship?

```
anomalies = request.user.aisle.get_anomalie_queryset.all()
```

There is my view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home_screen_view(request):

    context = {} 

    user_aisles = request.user.aisle.all()

    anomalies = request.user.aisle.get_anomalie_queryset.all()

    list_anomalies_user = []
    

    for aisle in user_aisles:
        print('aisle in user aisles list', aisle)
        user_aisle_type = type(aisle)
        print(user_aisle_type)
        for anomalie in anomalies:
            print(anomalie.aisle)
            if(aisle == anomalie.aisle):
                print("son iguales")
                tuple(list_anomalies_user)
                list_anomalies_user.append(anomalie)

    # is type list
    type_list = type(list_anomalies_user)
    print("tipo de dato de la lista anomalia user", type_list)
   
    type_anomalies = type(anomalies)
    print("tipo de dato de anomaliesr", type_anomalies)

    print("list_anomalies_user", list_anomalies_user)


    print('user aisles', user_aisles)
    print('anomalies', anomalies)

    context = {'anomalies': anomalies, 
'list_anomalies_user': list_anomalies_user}

    return render(request, "personal/home.html", context)
```

I will really thank you for your help!

Comment: whats your requirements of query basically